# Why the accordion is not working in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make a accordion using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The HTML and CSS is working well but the javaScript emplementation is not working. Can someone help me?

Files are here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nzEyyU_4QA4x_qh1QE_rz3V3DD_r7PAv?usp=sharing

I can't add code snippets because the stack overflow is not letting me submit the question.

Comment: Alternatively, you could paste your code into a JSFiddle and share the link.  See: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working script for you. Replace this with your javascript.

Working example I made on Codepen:
https://codepen.io/9to5disappear/pen/jOYBJJp

Javascript:

```
'use strict'

let label = document.getElementsByClassName('label');
let content = label.nextElementSibling;


const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
Array.from(elements).forEach((element, index) => {
    element.parentElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
        element.classList.toggle('content-visible');
    })   
});
```